# Why to use LinesOfCodeAvoidedAttribute class?

Tags: c#, postsharp

Reading the [sample](http://samples.postsharp.net/#PostSharp.Samples.CustomLogging/Aspects/LogMethodAttribute.cs) from PostSharp, I noticed something odd:

```
[LinesOfCodeAvoided(6)]
    public sealed class LogMethodAttribute : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
    {
```

According to the documentation, it says that LineOfCodeAvoided it's just a number specifying the quantity of lines of code avoided instead of writing those manually.

Is this attribute really necessary? Why exists?

I don't see any benefits and I suppose that "if I avoid to code N lines of code" that's something I know, no something I need to tell to my program, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the PostSharp code metrics is LOC Saved (Line of Code Saved). This attribute helps this metric to calculate how many lines you saved moving common code to aspects.

> Ready-made aspects are just a part of the story. Your custom aspects also participate in avoiding boilerplate code. To benefit from accurate code saving information, you will need to tell PostSharp how much lines are avoided every time your aspect is used.
>
> The easiest way is to add the [LinesOfCodeAvoided] attribute to your aspect class.

More information on [this](http://www.postsharp.net/blog/post/Announcing-PostSharp-42-Preview-4-Code-Saving-Metrics) blog entry

Comment: So basically it's just to help them by letting them know how many lines of code I avoided by implementing AOP. Thanks.